# A Date-time Label to be updated continuously

Tags: c#, winforms

```
lblDTIndicator.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy h:mmtt");
```

The label I have on the form is stuck on the current time for example, I run the program at 10:51 and even though it's 10:55 it doesn't update.  How would I have this be updated to be on par with the current latest time. I've tried looking online but haven't found one. I probably am not specific on my search so forgive me, if this seems like a trivial thing at hand. This is using a WinForm

Comment: Of course the label isn't going to update magically.  You need to write code to update it.  You could use a timer...

Comment: Is this win forms or web forms - You might want to let people know as they answer will be different.

Comment: @rory.ap as I said, forgive me for such a trivial thing. I haven't specify my search or probably didn't know how to search for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a Timer control and use it's Tick event to update the label.

Simply drag a Timer control to your form, set it's interval to 1 second or whatever update frequency you want.  Set it's enabled property to true.  Double click the timer control and paste this code in the Tick event:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblDTIndicator.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy h:mmtt");
}
```